# Classic ASP always return code 200 in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, trace

I enabled tracing in IIS7. 
I set those properties to true in the ASP tab of the IIS management tool:

- appAllowClientDebug,
- appAllowDebugging,
- errorsToNTLog,
- scriptErrorSentToBrowser;

To test it, I wrote a small classic ASP test page in wich I voluntary include a bug (bad activeX name).

My asp test page is rendered until the bug line is reached.  The rest of the page is not rendered. I was expecting a 500 error code, but code is always 200. There is no error file in the FailedReqLogFiles folder.

Any idea someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, i think the issue is actually with *Enable Server Side Debugging*. You may have it enabled, but you should *disable* it instead.

The server thinks it should start debugging and tries to fire up a debugger, and then doesn't find one and just gives up! I'm sure this never happened prior to IIS7.

Answer (score 2):

Glood Morning,

This problem was slowing our development significantly, because sql server errors were not displayed on the browser. Our Application Service Provider tried some settings, but couldn't get it to work. They sent me the settings and I accidentally did just two at once and our problem was fixed. They told me that asp was giving return code 200 instead of the error code.

Here is what worked for us:

The combination of "Send to Browser = True" and "Enable Server Side Debugging" = False" works.

I hope that helps others.

Tom Armstrong

Answer (score 0):

Look at this and see if this is stopping you from getting the 500 error. Also, If the bug is handled through an exception handler in the activeX then you might not be seeing an error on the asp response.

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-a-500-internal-server-error-for-all-asp-errors.html

200 OK is a Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The status code indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.

Comment: No. This is not helping.  IIS log shows me that the page has been accessed and resulting code was 200.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same IIS7 error happening. It was not returning any kind of error. There was no error message on the screen and no 500. The page just stopped rendering.

Is that what you are seeing? I can't remember what it was unfortunately, i think it was like something was handling the error. (If this is what you are seeing, i will keep trying to remember!)

I don't think this is it but it might be: go into Error Pages > Edit Feature Settings (hidden on the right panel) and select Detailed Error? That setting is also required and you didn't mention it.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i'm seeing.  Settings was already set to Detailed error.