# IIS 7.5 - "Enable server side debugging" without active debugger

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging

I have some troubles configuring IIS 7.5 on a Windows 2008 R2 server.
I need to debug .asp pages with Visual studio so I enabled "Enable server side debugging" in the asp debugging section on my website.

Everything goes right when i attach a debugger to w3wp process but if it's not attached and load an asp page with some errors in the code, in my browser i get only a blank page (with code 200).

It's something similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603994/classic-asp-always-return-code-200-in-iis7) but I can't set option to false because I need it.

So, is there a way to show the Error in the browser even if I don't have an active debugger attached to the iis process? I have already activated "send errors to browser" and in the Error section "Detailed error" is chosen.

Thank you very much

Riccardo

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453791/classic-asp-on-iis7-refusing-to-send-errors-to-browser-on-500-internal-server-e#

Comment: Thank you but as you can read i've already enabled "Detail errors" :(

Comment: Are your error pages coming from a local IP or a remote server?  If it's a remote server then this might be the problem - http://www.dondraper.com/2011/01/500-internal-server-error-from-iis-7-5-on-windows-2008-r2/

Comment: I have the same behaviour from the server itself or from a remote machine

Comment: Are you sure ASP classic pages can be debugged at all?  I think they are not compiled and hence you are limited by just the send errors to browser and then manually debugging.

Comment: ASP pages cannot be debugged, you need to set "send errors to browser" on remote requests.   That will tell you what line number the error is on and then you can debug manually.

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this. I have been able to do this for the past 15 or so years, but after reinstalling with Win10/IIS10/VS2017 it is no longer possible. @Frank - Millions of people have been debugging ASP pages in Visual Studio for the best part of 20 years! I can't believe you said that!